# plotting multiple charts in rPivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I want to plot multiple columns in rPivotTable.

Here is my dataset.

```
data_plot = data.frame(month = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), SALES = c(47, 90, 23, 75, 19, 28), promotions = c(3,4,2,5,1,2))
rpivotTable(data_plot)
```

[see here for pivot Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi17s.png)

[see here for pivot Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcewr.png)

I want to see the variations of Sales with promotions using a line Chart using rPivotTable. But I am not able to simultaneously visualize both the variables.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If  `data_plot` is reshaped from wide to long format, both variables can be plotted in one chart:

```
library(data.table)
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(melt(data_plot, id.var = "month"))
```

[image]

For reshaping, the `melt()` function from the `data.table` is used here.

```
melt(data_plot, id.var = "month")
```

> ```
>    month   variable value
> 1      1      SALES    47
> 2      2      SALES    90
> 3      3      SALES    23
> 4      1      SALES    75
> 5      2      SALES    19
> 6      3      SALES    28
> 7      1 promotions     3
> 8      2 promotions     4
> 9      3 promotions     2
> 10     1 promotions     5
> 11     2 promotions     1
> 12     3 promotions     2
> ```